# Yarn error while deploying application on the Google cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, yarnpkg

I have been trying to deploy this application(https://github.com/DivanteLtd/open-loyalty/) on Google cloud using Kubernetes.
The instance used to deploy this application contains Debian v4.9 as its OS. And we installed Docker, GCloud, Kubernetes, and Kompose as the tools for deployment. I built two docker images for the frontend and backend and linked them to the docker-compose file. Now in front-end model, we used (node:5) image from docker hub in Dockerfile of the frontend. Given below is the docker file of frontend container.

```
FROM node:5

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ruby-full rubygems \
    && gem instal sass
RUN npm install -g gulp node-sass yarn
COPY . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www
EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm rebuild node-sass && yarn install && gulp config --prod && gulp compile && gulp prod
```

I also tried using (node:6) and (node:7) as images but in error the node version remains v5.12.0 and npm version to be v3.8.6.
I also tried node-yarn(https://hub.docker.com/r/yarnpkg/node-yarn/) package specifically made for this issue.

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.8.6
npm info using node@v5.12.0
npm info readInstalled object
npm info ok
/bin/sh: 1: yarn: not found
```

A possible solution may be to change the image version of node in Dockerfile, but it remains same in error every time. But when I execute the same process on a local machine with (node:5), it works as expected.

Now for to run containers i am using "kompose up" which runs the docker-compose.yml file and deploys pods automatically. docker-compose.yml file is shown below.

```
backend:
  container_name: open-loyalty-backend
  image: gcr.io/open-loyalty/openloyalty_backend
  links:
    - elk
    - db
    - mail
  ports:
    - "8181:80"
  extra_hosts:
    - "web:127.0.0.1"
frontend:
  container_name: open-loyalty-frontend
  image: gcr.io/open-loyalty/openloyalty_frontend
  ports:
    - "8182:3000"
    - "8183:3001"
    - "8184:3002"
elk:
  container_name: open-loyalty-elk
  image: elasticsearch:2.2
db:
  container_name: open-loyalty-postgresql
  image: postgres
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=openloyalty
    - POSTGRES_USER=openloyalty
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=openloyalty
mail:
  container_name: open-loyalty-mail
  image: mailhog/mailhog
  ports:
    - "8186:8025"
```

So, is there any possible solution with this error?

Comment: Did you try `docker build --no-cache .` ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani i tried, but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that it's not working, but the yarn install docs specifically say you shouldn't install via npm.

> Note: Installation of Yarn via npm is generally not recommended. When
>   installing Yarn with Node-based package managers, the package is not
>   signed, and the only integrity check performed is a basic SHA1 hash,
>   which is a security risk when installing system-wide apps.
>
> For these reasons, it is highly recommended that you install Yarn
>   through the installation method best suited to your operating system.

On Debian, the installation would go like this:

```
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install yarn
```

If you are willing to run `node:8.4`, I can attest this method works on that image.

Also, confirm that the global node modules directory is in your PATH. Otherwise it won't be accessible on the command line. `npm root` will tell you where this is.

One thing that might help is to use an ENTRYPOINT script that will install yarn at runtime, immediately before you need to use it.

`ENTRYPOINT ["./entry.sh"]`

If you don't care about using yarn, and you just want the project to work, then simply use npm instead.

Comment: i tried (node:latest) too but it doesn't work. And also used this way of installing yarn by running these commands through dockerfile. Though same error.

Comment: Please post the method you are using to run the container.

Comment: I added the method to my question.